# VSCode API - 'textInputFocus' for webview or custom undo handling

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, vscode-extensions

I am working on VSCode extension implementation.
I am using webview for my extension - in result there is something similar to visual editor, when you can select items and edit.
In result I want to implement custom undo/redo handling for webview.
I have following code to handle VSCode's 'undo'/'redo' commands:

```
let undoCommand: Disposable;
let redoCommand: Disposable;
const registerCommands = () => {
    undoCommand = commands.registerCommand('undo', async (args) => {
        // Call custom undo handler
        triggerCustomUndo(appJsonFilePath, extensionWebView.webview);
        // Execute default undo handler
        return commands.executeCommand('default:undo', args);
    });
    redoCommand = commands.registerCommand('redo', async (args) => {
        // Call custom redo handler
        triggerCustomRedo(appJsonFilePath, extensionWebView.webview);
        // Execute default redo handler
        return commands.executeCommand('default:redo', args);
    });
};

extensionWebView.onDidChangeViewState((action: WebviewPanelOnDidChangeViewStateEvent) => {
    if (!action.webviewPanel.visible || !action.webviewPanel.active) {
        undoCommand.dispose();
        redoCommand.dispose();
    } else {
        registerCommands();
    }
});
registerCommands();
```

It works for me.
In result my custom undo/redo handler is called when I select 'undo'/'redo' from VSCode's menu:

[image: Menu image]

Problem is that when I am using 'Ctrl+Z'|'Command+Z' shortcut, then 'undo' command is not called for webview.

This happens because of following 'when' clause in default keybindings:

[image: When clause from default settings]

If I remove 'textInputFocus' statement from 'when' clause, then 'undo' command is called for webview when keyboard shortcut is used.
Some information regarding 'when' contexts - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/docs/getstarted/keybindings.md#contexts

**Question:**
Is there a way how I can set 'textInputFocus' to 'true', when I am using webview?

Alternative way could be:

- I can read keybinding attachments

  1. Default - 'vscode://defaultsettings/keybindings.json'
  2. Custom/Overwritten:
     Windows - %APPDATA%\Code\User\keybindings.json;
     MacOS - $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/keybindings.json;
     Linux - $HOME/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json;
- Attach to keyboard key down event manually and handle event to detect 'undo'/'redo' key combination;
  That should work, but if I could somehow set 'textInputFocus' to 'true' for webview then it would be much easier.

Or maybe there is other simpler solution available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found way how to set 'textInputFocus' manually:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'textInputFocus', true);
```